# Date comparison on input, client side MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a function that compares 2 dates, **Start_Date** and **End_Date**. If the start date is greater then the end date, alert a message saying "The start date exceeds End Date. Please check the date and re-enter it." **Also, this should be compared right after a click away from the text box.**

The below code doesn't seem to be doing justice. Any suggestions?

JS Code:

```
 $("td[start] > input").on("change", function () {
                alert("here first");
                var cur_td = $(this).closest("tr");
                var startdate = $(this).val();
                var enddate = cur_td.find("td[end]").text();
                var d1 = Date.parse(startdate);
                var d2 = Date.parse(enddate);
                checkdates(d1, d2);
            });
 function checkdates(s_date, e_date) {
                if (s_date > e_date) {
                    alert("The date " + s_date + " exceeds End Date. Please check the date and re-enter it.");
                }
            }
```

Razor View:

```
<td start><input class="start" id=@item.ID type="text" actual="1" value='@(item.Start_Date == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(item.Start_Date).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))' readonly="readonly" /></td>

<td end><input class="end" id=@item.ID type="text" actual="1" value='@(item.End_Date == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(item.End_Date).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))' readonly="readonly" /></td>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be doing justice" mean?  Do you get an error?

Comment: To begin with, can you first confirm that you are not getting any js error from your DOM itself? Your Razor view code is missing quotation mark for 'id' and even with that, the two td elements are given a same id (@item.ID) ids should be unique across the DOM

Comment: I am not getting any errors from the DOM.. Its just not taking in any change...

Comment: Thanks for the input, but on change works fine... I realized it was just out of scope :)

Answer (score 1):

You try 'keyup' instead of 'change.

```
$("td[start] > input").on("keyup", function () { })
```

or 
if you want to use on('change'), then you must use input type date or any date-picker.like

```
<input class="start" id=@item.ID type="date" actual="1" value='@(item.Start_Date == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(item.Start_Date).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))' readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but on change works fine... I realized it was just out of scope :)